# How to understand the LocalClusteringCoefficient use in directed graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, built-in-symbols

When this function use in undirected graphs,its action is normally and can be explained by this formula

$$CC_v=\frac{n}{C_{k}^{2}}=\frac{2n}{k(k-1)}$$

> n is adjacent nodes of $v$'s number of connected edge
>
> k is $v$'s number of adjacent nodes

This is a example about it

```
LocalClusteringCoefficient[
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4}]]
```

> {1,2/3,2/3,1}

But when it use in directed graph,I cannot understand its behavior like

## First example

```
g2 = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 
    3 -> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
Transpose[{VertexList@g2, LocalClusteringCoefficient[g2]}]
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}}
>
> ## Second example

```
g2 = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 
    3 -> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
Transpose[{VertexList@g2, LocalClusteringCoefficient[g2]}]
```

> {{1,1},{2,1/2},{3,1/3},{4,0}}

How to understand this two examples?

Comment: Something is wrong with the link to your picture. Please repost it, or preferably, use $\LaTeX$ to input it directly in the post.

Comment: @MarcoB First time to use $\LaTeX$ in SE :),Anyway I have rewrited it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Wow.Thinks for your link.I'll close this post soon.